# I want to search for 2 characters, is there any solution? (trigram index only works for minimum 3 characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance

I've got a trigram index on first and last name columns and I want to search for 2 characters. I tried to execute the query with sequential scans turned on or off and measure how long it takes in each case but it takes a lot of time in both. Is there a solution for my 2 characters search to work faster?

In schema I have :

> t.index "((((first_name)::text || ' '::text) || (last_name)::text))
>   gin_trgm_ops", name: "index_users_full_name", using: :gin

Comment: As the name suggests a **tri**gram is 3 consecutive characters. Is there a reason you would like to start at 2 characters because obviously the potential results compounds tremendously

Comment: My question is: What index should i use to help me even for the search of 2 characters?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built in to do this.  You could create a function that turns text into an array of bigrams (deciding what to do with spaces, punctuation, non-ASCII, etc.) and then index that array and query with `&&` operator.  But unless your two characters are something like 'qz', you might not get enough selectivity to make an index worthwhile.

```
create function bigram(text) returns text[] language sql as $$
    select array_agg(substring($1,x,2)) from generate_series(1,length($1)-1) f(x);
$$ immutable;

create index on foobar using gin (bigram(t));
select * from foobar where bigram(t) && bigram('aa');
```